# Repeatedly take n elements from a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have a list

```
lis={a,b,c,d,e,f};
```

Is there a way to get all the combination of 3 elements (without order) from it? I try to use

```
Flatten[Permutations /@ Subsets[lis, {3}], 1]
```

But it not contains the repeated elements, that is I want the elements such as `{a,a,a}` be included also.

Comment: @george2079 Tuples don't ignore order. I had this problem earlier today and wound up writing `Join[Subsets[extensions, {2}] , {#, #} & /@ extensions]` I hope I missed something...

Comment: `Sort/@Tuples//Union` ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using `Subsets` you can avoid deleting many duplicates

```
Multisets[s_List, n_Integer] := With[{u = Range[0, n - 1]},
        s[[# - u]] & /@ Subsets[Range[Length[s] + n - 1], {n}]]
Multisets[{a, b, c, d, e}, 3]
```

This vectorized version is probably faster:

```
Multisets[s_List, n_Integer] := Partition[s[[Flatten[Transpose[Subsets[
    Range[Length[s] + n - 1], {n}]] - Range[0, n - 1], {2, 1}]]], n]
```

Comment: Really nice method!

Comment: this wins the timing tests.. ( the first form beats the second in some cases for long input lists )

Answer (score 6):

There are more solutions maybe this is the shortest.

```
Union[Sort /@ Tuples[Table[{a, b, c, d, e}, {3}]]]
(* {{a, a, a}, {a, a, b}, {a, a, c}, {a, a, d}, {a, a, e}, {a, b,
   b}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, d}, {a, b, e}, {a, c, c}, {a, c, d}, {a, c, 
  e}, {a, d, d}, {a, d, e}, {a, e, e}, {b, b, b}, {b, b, c}, {b, b, 
  d}, {b, b, e}, {b, c, c}, {b, c, d}, {b, c, e}, {b, d, d}, {b, d, 
  e}, {b, e, e}, {c, c, c}, {c, c, d}, {c, c, e}, {c, d, d}, {c, d, 
  e}, {c, e, e}, {d, d, d}, {d, d, e}, {d, e, e}, {e, e, e}} *)
```

Comment: This can be shortened to `Union[Sort /@ Tuples[{a, b, c, d, e}, {3}]]`

Comment: this is good for readability so long as the list is short, but note you'll run out of memory quickly for longer lists..

Answer (score 3):

another approach:

```
unsortedtuples[input_,n_] := 
 Module[{p}, 
  Nest[Flatten[
     Function[{subl}, p = Position[input, Last@subl][[1, 1]]; 
       Append[subl, #] & /@ input[[;; p]]] /@ #, 1] &, 
   Transpose@{input}, n-1]]
unsortedtuples[{a, b, c, d},4]
```

> ```
>  
>         {{a, a, a, a}, {b, a, a, a}, {b, b, a, a}, {b, b, b, a}, 
>          {b, b, b, b}, {c, a, a, a}, {c, b, a, a}, {c, b, b, a}, 
>          {c, b, b, b}, {c, c, a, a}, {c, c, b, a}, {c, c, b, b},
>          {c, c, c, a}, {c, c, c, b}, {c, c, c, c}, {d, a, a, a},
>          {d, b, a, a}, {d, b, b, a}, {d, b, b, b}, {d, c, a, a},
>          {d, c, b, a}, {d, c, b, b}, {d, c, c, a}, {d, c, c, b}, 
>          {d, c, c, c}, {d, d, a, a}, {d, d, b, a}, {d, d, b, b},
>          {d, d, c, a}, {d, d, c, b}, {d, d, c, c}, {d, d, d, a},
>          {d, d, d, b}, {d, d, d, c}, {d, d, d, d}}
> ```

note this assumes no repeated elements in the input. (Probably just do `Union` on the input if that's an issue, otherwise I'm not sure what the result should be )